# Gauldur legend quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I find the Gauldur Amulet Fragment for a stamina increase? I want to get the full amulet, but I lack the stamina fragment. Can someone tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Should really consider looking at the various Skyrim wikis before posting some of these questions.

Comment: @DCShannon I know that I can use other websites to find information on video games, and although they are limited to several websites that aren't even that informative, I prefer to use this website. I mean if we can just find the answers to our questions on different websites, what's the point of this one. I could have just used a different device to find the answer to this question easily but I, personally, think we should be able to ask any reasonable questions. It gives me, you and many other users to learn and share knowledge while having fun so I really hope that people can consider this.

Comment: You're supposed to check other websites before looking here, and post any research you did in the question. If you can find the info elsewhere, especially at an established and commonly used wiki, then asking the question indicates a lack of research, which is a downvote criteria. You might look over the [guide to asking a good question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Note this part: "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geirmund's hall, Saarthal and Fothungur are the place that you can find the amulets. Saarthal having the magicka amulet, geirmund's hall having the stamina and fothungur having the health amulet

Answer (score 5):

The stamina's amulet fragment is in the [Geirmund's Hall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Geirmund%27s_Hall).
You have to slain [Sigdis Gauldurson](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sigdis_Gauldurson) (the amulet fragment is lootable from his body).

[**Source**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend)